# How much power does the voltage source with \$12V\$ provide to the circuit? Which part of my calculation is wrong?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, homework

How much power does the voltage source with \$12V\$ provide to the circuit?

The answer is \$84W\$

[image]

My thinking:

The question asks me "How much power does the voltage source with \$12V\$" provide to the circuit, so I think I should ignore the voltage source with \$-6V\$, that is, see the voltage source with \$-6V\$ as a short circuit, then the circuit will become like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsTzNZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously,\$R4||R2,R3||R2,R3||R1\$,so these resistances are parallel connected to each others,so the \$R_{th}=R4||R1||R2||R3=6||6||12||12=3||6=2\$.

And the power of voltage source with \$12V\$ is  \$P_{12}=\frac{V^2}{R}=\frac{12^2}{2}=\frac{144}{2}=72W\$, however, as I said in the beginning,the answer should be \$84W\$,so does someone know which part of thinking am I wrong in my calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *does someone know which part of thinking am i wrong in my
>   calculation??*

You can't ignore the 6 volt source. You have to calculate the net current into or out of the 12 volt source and you might use superposition (you are actually half way there with shorting the 6 volt source) or some other circuit analysis technique like "simplification": -

[image]

You should be able to pretty much see straight away that the 12 volt source is supplying 3 amps to the 6 ohm resistor and 4 amps to the 3 ohm resistor.

The next step is too trivial to mention.

Comment: the 12 volt source is supplying 3 amps to the 6 ohm resistor and 4 amps to the 3 ohm resistor.so the \$P_{6Ω}=3^2 \times 6=54W\$,and \$P_{3Ω}=4^2 \times 3=48W\$,so the power that that \$12V\$ voltage source provide should be \$54W+48W=102 \neq  84W\$,still the wrong answer

Comment: @XM551 You can't use that formula when there is another voltage source involved with the \$R_{6\Omega}\$ resistor. You can with the other resistor but, it's simpler to just calculate power directly: the 12 volt supply is providing 3+4 amps = 7 amps hence, the power delivered is 7*12 = 84 watts.

Comment: Using \$P_{6\Omega} = 3^2 \times 6\$ calculates the power dissipated by the 6 ohm resistor and not the power supplied to it by the 12 volt source.

Comment: thank you,now i know how to calculate it

Answer (score 4):

The part where you decided that the -6V supply can be ignored and replaced with a short circuit is wrong, you end up with less current being drawn out of the battery.